# How to search with partial word with Solr

Tags: search, drupal, solr

I'm trying search-api and search-api-solr modules and Solr to search with match partial words that are in the middle of a word, and aren't necessarily at the beginning of a word.
I use 
`<filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="25" />`

but still it doesn't work properly?

Any advice?

my English text field in schema_extra_types.xml
Note: there are other text fields in schema_extra_types.xml but I currently try with the English field.

```
<!--
  English Text Field
  7.0.0 --> <fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="accents_en.txt"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords_en.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory" catenateNumbers="1" generateNumberParts="1" protected="protwords_en.txt"
splitOnCaseChange="0" generateWordParts="1" preserveOriginal="1" catenateAll="0" catenateWords="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="2" max="100"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords_en.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="25" />
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="accents_en.txt"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms_en.txt" expand="true" ignoreCase="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords_en.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory" catenateNumbers="0" generateNumberParts="1" protected="protwords_en.txt"
splitOnCaseChange="0" generateWordParts="1" preserveOriginal="1" catenateAll="0" catenateWords="0"/>
    <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="2" max="100"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords_en.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer> </fieldType>
```

Comment: What is the content indexed for the field and what is your query? Combining the `SnowballPorterFilter` might give you results you're not expecting, since they'll attempt to stem a word.

Comment: @MatsLindh I forget to reindex, it works now. thanks